# How to design Webpage that work on each resolution

Tags: html, css, gwt

As I developed application in GWT technology, It works on Desktop only. I assign height & width of panel using

**Width/Height by relative percentage:** just example:

```
((Window.getClientWidth()*10)/100)+"px"
(Window.getClientHeight()*95/100)+"px"
```

As I assign pixel to widget according to screen resolution. Even though it shows scroll bar issues. why is this not work for all resolution perfectly?

Note: using **1024*768**

how can I create layout which works for all resolution?

should I have to check only 1024*768 resolution? If yes than higher resolution shows white unnecessary spaces? How to do it?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

you could try using media queries, check this http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/03/how-to-build-a-mobile-website/

Comment: I need only for desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its not possible to support ALL resolutions, however for below link has solution that can work for some selected resolutions.

http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/advanced_web_design.asp